# OhGoogleMapFormTypeBundle with SonataAdminBundle

Tags: php, google-maps, symfony, sonata-admin

What should I do to make this bundle work with `SonataAdminBundle`? I configured `OhGoogleMapFormTypeBundle` basing on [README](https://github.com/ollietb/OhGoogleMapFormTypeBundle/blob/master/README.md).
This is my `configureFormFields` method:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->with("Map")
            ->add('latlng', new GoogleMapType())
        ->end()
    ;
}
```

I'm getting error:

```
Please define a type for field `latlng` in `GM\AppBundle\Admin\PlaceAdmin`
```

Comment: You can use this bundle instead https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryGoogleMapBundle

Comment: Thanks @benjaminLazarecki. Could you write something about integration with forms in SonataAdminBundle?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So really there is a problem with FormMapper.
The solution was quite simple, but to find it spent a lot of time.
There are two ways:

The **first** method (I did not like):

```
$form = new YourType();
$form->buildForm($formMapper->getFormBuilder(),array());
```

**Second** method:

```
->add('latlng', 'sonata_type_immutable_array',array('label' => 'Карта',
      'keys' => array(
                    array('latlng', new GoogleMapType(), array())
                )))
```

***Entity:***

```
public function setLatLng($latlng)
{
   $this
      ->setLatitude($latlng['latlng']['lat'])
      ->setLongitude($latlng['latlng']['lng']);
   return $this;
}

/**
* @Assert\NotBlank()
* @OhAssert\LatLng()
*/
public function getLatLng()
{
   return array('latlng' => array('lat' => $this->latitude,'lng' => $this->longitude));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jura-kor, it is almost correct because now I'm getting blank map in my form. Is this a template issue? I tried `install:assets` and `cache:clear` with no effect.

Comment: in javascript console I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ohGoogleMapType'`

Comment: I forgot about:
assetic:dump
assets:install
:)

Comment: It doesn't update entity's coordinates this way. Still set functions seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

I first defined the `GoogleMapType` as a service, in the  `app/config.yml` file:

```
services:
    # ...
    oh.GoogleMapFormType.form.type.googlemapformtype:
        class: Oh\GoogleMapFormTypeBundle\Form\Type\GoogleMapType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: oh_google_maps }
```

I'm kinda noob with Symfony2, so I don't know why by some reason the alias must be `oh_google_maps`.

Then, I set up the fields and functions for storing the latitude and longitude in my Entity class:

```
private $latlng;

private $latitude;

private $longitude;

public function setLatlng($latlng)
{
    $this->latlng = $latlng;
    $this->latitude = $latlng['lat'];
    $this->longitude = $latlng['lng'];
    return $this;
}

/**
* @Assert\NotBlank()
* @OhAssert\LatLng()
*/
public function getLatLng()
{
    return array('lat' => $this->latitude,'lng' => $this->longitude);
}
```

Finally, in my custom Sonata Admin class, at the `configureFormFields` function:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        //...
        ->add('latlng', 'oh_google_maps', array());
}
```